# How to fix column count doesn't match the row value count

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked on many different sites including php.net and still haven't found out why my insert script isn't working. I'm using Eclipse to program in PHP and I have the PHP add-on installed so that it works correctly but I haven't figured out what's wrong with my script.

Ex.

```
switch($type) {

    case(1):
        require("opendb.php");
        $query = "INSERT INTO ability(AbilityName,Description,Strength,Defense,Luck,Agility) values ('" . $name . '","' . $description . '","' . $strength . '","' . $defense . '","' . $luck . '","' . $agility . "')";
        if (!mysql_query($query)) {
            echo "Ability was not entered successfully: " . mysql_error();
        } else {
            echo "Ability was entered successfully!";
        }
        break;
    case(2):
        require("opendb.php");
        $query = "INSERT INTO weapon(WeaponName,Description,Strength,Defense,Luck,Agility) values ('"  . $name . '","' . $description . '","' . $strength . '","' . $defense . '","' . $luck . '","' . $agility . "')";
        if (!mysql_query($query)) {
            echo "Weapon was not entered successfully: " . nysql_error();
        } else {
            echo "Weapon was entered successfully!";
        }
        break;
    default:
        require("opendb.php");
        $query = "INSERT INTO item(ItemName,Description,Strength,Defense,Luck,Agility) values ('" . $name . '","' . $description . '","' . $strength . '","' . $defense . '","' . $luck . '","' . $agility . "')";
        if (!mysql_query($query)) {
            echo "Item was not entered successfully: " . mysql_error();
        } else {
            echo "Item was entered successfully!";
        }
    }
}
```

You're suppose to be able to select the radio button to insert an object as either an item, weapon, or ability but I keep getting the column value doesn't match the row value count error. Here are the three tables that I created. The ID's are incrementing automatically each time an object is entered. It isn't null but I shouldn't need to include the ID on the form that I'm using to enter the object.

item table:

```
ItemID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ItemName varchar(40),
Description longtext,
Strength INT NOT NULL,
Defense INT NOT NULL,
Luck INT NOT NULL,
Agility INT NOT NULL
```

weapon table:

```
WeaponID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
WeaponName varchar(40),
Description longtext,
Strength INT NOT NULL,
Defense INT NOT NULL,
Luck INT NOT NULL,
Agility INT NOT NULL
```

ability table:

```
AbilityID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
AbilityName varchar(40),
Description longtext,
Strength INT NOT NULL,
Defense INT NOT NULL,
Luck INT NOT NULL,
Agility INT NOT NULL
```

Comment: Do you get the errors when the query isn't successful?

Comment: Please consider using a database layer like `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of the plain `mysql` extension: your code seems to be wide open for sql injection...

Comment: You need to dump $query somewhere when it fails. I am guessing one of your INTs (Strength,Defense,Luck,Agility) is actually not coming in as an int so isn't casting properly.

Comment: You need to specify a `NULL` value for the auto increment column, don't you?

Comment: I'm going to work on securing it arkascha. Eritrea, it is when it's not successful. I'll look it it Omnikrys

Comment: You shouldn't as I've done a previous code for a game for a class and I didn't need it.

Comment: just tried it in SQLyog after creating the same tables. Works fine. Not to do with the problem but you shouldn't repeat require("opendb.php"); in each switch case since it's in all just put it above the switch.

Comment: Are your strings escaped? If not one of them could be causing values() to have an extra column. E.g. $description="foo','bar";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using invalid string quotation, which is a simple syntax error in your SQL command.

If you echo this line,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ability(AbilityName,Description,Strength,Defense,Luck,Agility) values ('" . $name . '","' . $description . '","' . $strength . '","' . $defense . '","' . $luck . '","' . $agility . "')";
```

The output will be like:

```
INSERT INTO ability(AbilityName,Description,Strength,Defense,Luck,Agility) values ('name","description","strength","defense","luck","agility')
```

As you can see, first and last columns use mixed string quotation which causes the error. I suggest you to use only single quotes in your SQL queries and use [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) method for creating these strings in PHP.